# STL container sizeof reqirement

Tags: c++, stl

Is there any requirement on STL container `sizeof`s? For example I could implement `std::list` using `Node` as follows:

```
struct Node
{
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    T value;
};
```

and store two pointer or object of Node such as:

```
Node* m_head;
Node* m_tail;
```

or

```
Node m_head;
Node m_tail;
```

Considering that value type `T` can be massive, the `sizeof` of `list` can be very large. Is it acceptable?

Comment: OOC, how are you going to deal with lists of size 0 in that case? You'll always have at least one non-tail node.

Comment: @tobi303 I think he's talking about the *container* definition, not the node definition. I did a double-take too.

Comment: No need of any code as the question is very general. **Do STL containers have `sizeof` requirement?**

Comment: Considering `std::array`s contain *all* their elements in their bodies, I find it unlikely you'd be doing anything beyond what they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no requirement in the standard of what the size of the container should be.  What the standard details is what the behavior of the data structure is.  It also details the complexity of the operations done to it and of its member functions.  This in turn may limit how you design it in order to conform to those requirements but if you can figure out how to maintain those requirements in a different way the standard allows that.

Answer (score 2):

There's no specific restriction on the container memory footprint, but the container can't be implemented the way you suggest.

Because the container constructor doesn't know how<sup>1</sup> to construct objects of type `T`, there can't be any (nested) members of type `T`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Having a element type default constructor or a copy constructor is a requirement for certain container operations, but the Standard doesn't require those for `std::list::list(void)` or `std::list::list(Allocator&)`, so implementations have to do without.

[image: std::list constructor semantics]

Comment: Standard containers get around figuring out how to construct `T` for their size-based constructors by offering a `T const&` argument to copy-construct from, defaulted to `T()`. Why wouldn't that work for constructing the `T` here?

Comment: @jaggedSpire: Because the container constructor signatures are specified in the Standard, you can't refuse to provide the signatures that don't have `T const&` arguments.  And some constructors are specified to work for move-only element types, so you can't write them to call copy constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the C++ standard expressly forbidding the `sizeof` to be zero (otherwise pointer arithmetic would break horribly), a C++ standard library implementation can set a container `sizeof` to anything it chooses.

Note further, for example, that `sizeof(std::list<T>)` does not necessarily have to be the same as `sizeof(std::list<Y>)` for different types `T` and `Y`.